# react-select: multi value dropdowns do not close on outside click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have two multi value `react-select` drodowns as part of a bigger filter component. The issue I am encountering is when you open one of the dropdowns, select one or more values and click outside of it, then the dropdown does not close.

If you click outside of the dropdown without selecting any value then it closes as expected. If you select a value and close the dropdown by clicking in the control and open it again, then it closes on outside click.

Code to reproduce the issue is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wildflower-evmi0z

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-select wont close when clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128524/react-select-wont-close-when-clicking-outside)