# How can I close my react-select on click outside?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

```
const Filters= ({ label, placeholder, value, options, onChange}) => {
    return (
        <FiltersStyled>
            <h4>{label}</h4>
            <div>
                <Select placeholder={placeholder} value={value} onChange={onChange} isClearable={false} options={options} isMulti closeMenuOnSelect={false} noOptionsMessage={() => ''} hideSelectedOptions={false} components={{ ValueContainer }} />
            </div>
        </FiltersStyled>
    )
}

const ValueContainer = ({ hasValue, children, getValue, ...props }) => {
    let [values, input] = children;
    if (Array.isArray(values)) {
        const { length } = values;

        if (getValue().length > 0 && getValue().length <= 3) {
            values = getValue().map(x => x.label).join(', ')
        } else {
            const otherCount = length - 3;
            values = getValue().slice(0, 3).map(x => x.label).join(', ') + ` + ${otherCount}`
        }
    }

    return (
        <Select.components.ValueContainer {...props}>
            {values}
            {!hasValue && input}
        </Select.components.ValueContainer>
    );
}
```

This is my react-select I create a custom container, my issue is when I click outside with the custom container it doesn't close my react-select

When i pass from `components={{ ValueContainer }}` to `components={ ValueContainer }` my custom component doesn't work and it shows me the inital component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-select wont close when clicking outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128524/react-select-wont-close-when-clicking-outside)

Comment: @SumitParakh No because when i pass from `components={{ ValueContainer }}` to `components={ ValueContainer }` my custom component doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the contains() function is not available on the current value of selectRef.current. This could happen if selectRef.current is null or undefined, or if it is not an object that has a contains() function.

```
const App = () => {
  const selectRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  });

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (selectRef.current && typeof selectRef.current.contains === 'function' && !selectRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      selectRef.current.select.clearValue();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select ref={selectRef} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have this error :

> selectRef.current.contains is not a function

Comment: @user10863293 I have updated the code please check now

Comment: When I click outside it doesn't work